# Spivak, Ch. 24, Problem 6: Is there a relatively easy way to find $f^{(k)}(0)$ for $f(x)=\sin{x}/x, f(0)=1$ using power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

> 6. If $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$, find $f^{(k)}(0)$. Hint: Find the power series for $f$.

Here is what the solution manual says

> Since
>
> $$\sin{x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
>
> we have
>
> $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
>
> (notice that the right side is $1$ for $x=0$). So
>
> $$f^{(k)}(0)=\begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}, k=2n \\ 0, k \text{ odd } \end{cases}\tag{1}$$

As is customary with the solution manual, it skips all the intermediate steps. The comment in parentheses indicates that every time the exponent on $x$ is even then there is some $n$ for which it is zero and thus the entire term is a constant. I understand the solution intuitively. All you have to do is write out the series to notice that for even derivatives the first term is a constant, but for odd derivatives all terms contain an $x$.

I can't seem to see this analytically though.

Here is what I had

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2n-k}}{(2n-k)!}$$

Now, if $k$ is even, then $n_0=k/2$, and the first term is $\frac{(-1)^{n_0}}{2n_0+1}$.

If $k$ is odd, then $n_0=\frac{k-1}{2}$ (this is kind of a hunch, I didn't actually prove this, and being comfortable believing it made me waste a lot of time) and the first term is $\frac{(-1)^{n_0}}{2n_0+1}x$.

Therefore,

$$f^{(k)}(0)=\begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}, k \text{ even } \\ 0, k \text{
odd } \end{cases}\tag{1}$$

It seems I have found the same result as the solution manual. The reason I am asking this question is that I spent an absurd amount of time to figure this out, and even now it seems like a sketchy process I used.

Is there an easier way to manipulate the sum so as to reach (1) with less pain and suffering?

Comment: Why did you have to differentiate the power series again. I’m sure in the beginning of the text (maybe the chspter on Taylor polynomials or in the chapter on power series), Spivak tells you that if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-p)^n$ is a power series, then the derivatives are calculated as $f^{(k)}(p)=k!a_k$ for all integer $k\geq 0$. So, for your series, you first have to figure out $a_k$ depending on whether it is odd/even, and then just apply this formula.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. In the title you write “how to find the power series ...” but you already have $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$. That *is* a power series.

Comment: I find your attempt hard to follow. Why are you asking for a power series for $f(x)$ if the solution gives you the power series? The power series for $\sin(x)$ is given to you, so you can just divide by $x$ on both sides. And where does $n_0$ come from?

Comment: @MartinR I changed the title to be more accurate: we want to find $f^{(k)}(0)$ using the power series of $f$.

Comment: @Accelerator What I think I noticed is that as we differentiate, the sums start from 0 then 0, then 1, then 1, then 2, then 2, then, 3, then 3. That is we have $\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^infty$ and $n_0$ is 0 for the power series of $f$ and $f'$, then it is 1 for $f''$ and $f'''$, and so on.

Comment: The main issue I have is how to spot the difference between even and odd derivatives with regards to the first element having or not having an $x$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with my solution (and that makes reasoning about it painful) is the fact that I manipulated the summation terms in a way that wasn't ideal.

We have

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1}$$

$$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot 2n \cdot \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1a}$$

and

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot 2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)...\cdot (2n-(k-1)) \cdot \frac{x^{2n-k}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1b}$$

From (1b) we can see that if $k$ is even the terms for $n=1,2,...\left ( \frac{k-2}{2}\right )$ will all be $0$ because some one term in

$$2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)...\cdot (2n-(k-1))$$

is $0$.

For $n=k/2$, however, we have the term

$$(-1)^n\cdot 2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)...\cdot (2n-(k-1))\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$=k!\frac{(-1)^{k/2}}{(k+1)!}$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^{k/2}}{k+1}\tag{2}$$

and all subsequent terms have an $x$ factor. Therefore $f^{(k)}(0)$ is just (2).

On the other hand, if $k$ is odd, then the terms for $n=1,2,...,\left (\frac{k-1}{2}\right )$ are all $0$, and all subsequent terms have an $x$ factor. Therefore $f^{(k)}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$\sin' = \cos
$,
$\cos' = -\sin
$,
$\sin(0) = 0$,
$\cos(0) = 1$,
and
$\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1$.

For small $t$,
$1 \ge \cos(t)
\ge 0
$
so
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\le x
$.
Therefore
$1-\cos(x)
=\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\le \int_0^x t dt 
= \frac{t^2}{2}
$
so
$\cos(t)
\ge 1-\frac{t^2}{2}
$.

Therefore
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\ge\int_0^x (1-\frac{t^2}{2})dt
=x-\frac{x^3}{6}
$.

So we already have
$x-\frac{x^3}{6}
\le \sin(x)
\le x
$.

Doing this again,
$1-\cos(x)
=\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\ge \int_0^x (t-\frac{t^3}{6}) dt 
= \frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}
$
so
$\cos(t)
\le 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}
$.

Doing this one more time,
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\le\int_0^x (1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24})dt
=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}
$.

By induction,
we can get the power series
for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Note:
This is not original.
I first saw this in
"100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics"
by Heinrich Dorrie
(less that $15 from Dover).

Get it.

Comment: Not what he is asking about.

Comment: Once you have the power series, just take the k-th term.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing that you are not seeing is that the series
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\cdots$$
Is missing some terms. Really it should read,
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1+0x-\frac{x^2}{3!}-0x^3+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\cdots$$
So you should write
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\ a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{(n+1)!} & \operatorname{mod}(n,4)=0 \\ \frac{-1}{(n+1)!} & \operatorname{mod}(n,4)=2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Or better yet as
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\operatorname{sinc}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin(\pi n/2)}{(n+1)!}x^n \\ =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin(\pi n/2)}{n+1}x^n$$
Now that we have included **all** the terms, even the odd ones which are zero, this now precisely the Taylor series ($f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)~x^n$), and so we can say
$$\operatorname{sinc}^{(m)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^{m+1}\sin(\pi m/2)}{m+1}$$
Now tell me, what happens when $m=2k$ is even or $m=2k+1$ is odd?